# How to move nested objects to a different object in jq?

Tags: json, jq

I need to restructure some JSON files to clean up the data representation. Part of this restructuring includes grouping similar objects in a parent object rather than relying on a particular property of the object. We will have five "sections" in the files:

`attributes`, `associatedObjects`, `inheritedObjects`, `enumerations`, which will be used to represent "active" objects, and then a `deprecated` section that has those same four subgroups to denote, well, "deprecated" objects. The deprecated objects will be subject to later removal.

Given a structure such as:

```
    "attributes": {
        "alpha": {
            "deprecated": true,
            "description": "A description of alpha.",
            "dataType": "string"
        },
        "beta": {
            "deprecated": false,
            "description": "A description of beta.",
            "dataType": "associated object",
            "associatedObject": "gamma"
        },
        "kappa": {
            "deprecated": false,
            "description": "A description of kappa.",
            "dataType": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

How might I reorganize the file using `jq` to appear more like the following?

```
    "deprecations": {
        "attributes": {
            "alpha": {
                "description": "A description of alpha.",
                "dataType": "string"
            }
        },
        "enumerations": {},
        "associatedObjects": {},
        "inheritedObjects": {}
    },
    "attributes": {
        "kappa": {
            "description": "A description of kappa.",
            "dataType": "string"
        }
    },
    "enumerations": {},
    "associatedObjects": {
        "beta": {
            "description": "A description of beta.",
            "dataType": "gamma"
        }
    },
    "inheritedObjects": {}
}
```

I've only been able to add the new, empty sections (without any nesting) at the same level as `attributes` via `jq '.associatedObjects = {} | .inheritedObjects = {} | .enumerations = {} | .deprecations = {} '`

I attempted to move the item flagged as `deprecated` via this command:

```
jq '.attributes | keys[] as $k | 
if (.[$k].deprecated == true) then 
(del(.[$k].deprecated) | .deprecated += .[$k] | del(.[$k])) 
else empty end '
```

but this results in invalid JSON and seems to duplicate the structure. I've also not been able to combine it with the creation of the new sections. It appears I don't have to create those new sections separately and/or beforehand.

What would it take to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot entirely follow the criteria for your distribution, especially `.enumerations` and `.inheritedObjects` are unclear, but this could get you going:

```bash
.attributes | (map_values(select(.dataType == "string")) | {
  deprecations: map_values(select(.deprecated)),
  attributes: map_values(select(.deprecated | not))
}) + {
  associatedObjects: map_values(select(.dataType == "associated object"))
}
```

```json
{
  "deprecations": {
    "alpha": {
      "deprecated": true,
      "description": "A description of alpha.",
      "dataType": "string"
    }
  },
  "attributes": {
    "kappa": {
      "deprecated": false,
      "description": "A description of kappa.",
      "dataType": "string"
    }
  },
  "associatedObjects": {
    "beta": {
      "deprecated": false,
      "description": "A description of beta.",
      "dataType": "associated object",
      "associatedObject": "gamma"
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/MmbokVP-5Mv)

Comment: You can add the filter `del(.deprecated)` after the distribution

Answer (score 1):

This should generate the expected output :

```
jq '(.attributes | map_values(select(.deprecated))) as $dep
    | .depreciations.attributes = ($dep | map_values(del(.deprecated)))
    | (.attributes | map_values(select(has("associatedObject")))) as $assoc
    | .associatedObjects = ($assoc
                           | map_values(.dataType = .associatedObject)
                           | map_values(del(.deprecated, .associatedObject))
                           )
    | .attributes |= del(.[]|select(.deprecated))
    | .attributes |= del(.[]|select(has("associatedObject")))
    | .attributes[] |= del(.deprecated)
    | .depreciations += { "enumerations": {}, "associatedObjects": {}, "inheritedObjects": {} }
    | . + { "enumerations": {}, "inheritedObjects": {} }
' input.json
```

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "kappa": {
      "description": "A description of kappa.",
      "dataType": "string"
    }
  },
  "depreciations": {
    "attributes": {
      "alpha": {
        "description": "A description of alpha.",
        "dataType": "string"
      }
    },
    "enumerations": {},
    "associatedObjects": {},
    "inheritedObjects": {}
  },
  "associatedObjects": {
    "beta": {
      "description": "A description of beta.",
      "dataType": "gamma"
    }
  },
  "enumerations": {},
  "inheritedObjects": {}
}
```